# How to get my floated divs to look consistant across major browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to throw together a portfolio site for myself, but i've only just started testing on other computers. Today i noticed an issue with some floated divs being positioned incorrectly in IE and Firefox.

Chrome looks correct, pictured left, internet explorer pictured right
[image]

The floated divs are .projects defined like so:

```
.project {
    margin: 2.5em 1.5em 0 0;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

I understand that projects can have different amounts of text and slightly different image dimensions which may be the cause, but i don't know how i can ensure consistent positioning as seen in Chrome?

Feel free to fiddle with the actual website in browser: [www.holly.im](http://holly.im/)

Appreciate any help!

....I really should ask this as a separate question, but i may as well mention it here- I get a lot of extra space below the content of the pages in Firefox, I can scroll down over plain gray for a while which i don't really understand since the majority of my website content exists inside the #pages div which firebug highlighting tells me ends where it should. Thought it worth asking about? but i'll probably post a separate question.

Comment: Try to post your HTML to, i know you posted the website which is great but it wouldn't help future people if the site is gone

Comment: make sure IE is not in 'Quirks' mode either.

Comment: most likely issue is that then text expands to two lines where is no room for image below and it drops down. Set height to your `.project` div and should be fixed.

Comment: Hi Holly,  I'm trying to check out your webpage but it seems to take me directly to the about page with the Resume link on it.  I think there may be some javascript craziness going on there as it immediately scrolls me to the far right of the page on page load and I'm not able to navigate back.  Just thought I'd let you know (using Chrome by the way).

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a `clear:left` after your third `.project` or set a fixed height on your `.project` divs.

As you second title is longer it is causing the floated divs on the line below to stack behind it which is pushing the last two down a line